# Why is the value of [this] keyword in Base class constructor equals to the Derived class after calling super in the Derived class?

Tags: javascript

```
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this); /*break point here in chrome debugger*/
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

`new Derived();`
Why value of [this] = Derived in the Local Scope inside the constructor of the Base class?

`new Base();`
The value of [this] = Base in the Local Scope as I was expecting.

Comment: See [How does the “this” keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212). It explains everything. `super()` calls the `constructor` of `Base` with `this` set to the `Derived` instance. `this` is neither `Base` nor `Derived` in both of your examples.

Comment: @SebastianSimon So after calling `super()` in the `Derived` class, in the `Base` class constructor we've the code evaluation similar to this? `class Base { constructor() { this = new Derived(); }}` ?

Comment: Kind of… the instantiation already happens at the original `new Derived();`. You can imagine the `super` call like an implicit `super(this);` and `class Base { constructor(thisRef){ console.log(thisRef); } }`. Or, in the older prototypal pattern (if you’re familiar with it), `super()` works like `Base.call(this)`, passing `this` (the instance of `Derived`) to `Base`, where it also will be usable as `this`.

Comment: `super(this)` This is helping me to visualize. Thanks

Comment: @SebastianSimon - *"... the instantiation already happens at the original new Derived()..."* Not with JavaScript's `class` syntax. The instantiation doesn't happen until the base class constructor is reached. (This is different from the way it worked with chained constructors in ES5 and earlier.) It's literally the base class constructor that creates the instance (using the `new.target` it was passed through the chain). (This is part of why `this` can't be used before `super`.)

Answer (score 2):

`this` isn't either `Base` or `Derived` in your examples. It's an **instance** of `Base` and (where you use `new Derived`) also an instance of `Derived`.

When you do `new Derived`, `this` is created as an instance of `Derived`. It doesn't matter whether you look at it in the `Base` constructor or the `Derived` constructor, in both cases `this` refers to the **single** object created by using `new` (which is an instance of both `Base` and `Derived`).

Here's some other logging that may be more useful:

```js
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log(
            "In Base:   ",
            this instanceof Base,
            this instanceof Derived,
            this.constructor.name
        );
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(
            "In Derived:",
            this instanceof Base,
            this instanceof Derived,
            this.constructor.name
        );
    }
}

new Derived();
// =>
// In Base:    true true Derived
// In Derived: true true Derived
```

We can go further to prove it's the same object (you wouldn't store the value of `this` on a global variable in real code, but this is to see what's going on in this specific example):

```js
let thisInBase;
class Base {
    constructor() {
        thisInBase = this;
        console.log(
            "In Base:   ",
            this instanceof Base,
            this instanceof Derived,
            this.constructor.name
        );
    }
}

let thisInDerived;
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        thisInDerived = this;
        console.log(
            "In Derived:",
            this instanceof Base,
            this instanceof Derived,
            this.constructor.name
        );
    }
}

const instance = new Derived();
// =>
// In Base:    true true Derived
// In Derived: true true Derived
console.log(instance === thisInBase);
// => true
console.log(instance === thisInDerived);
// => true
```

Comment: I would nitpick that `this` is not an instance of `base` and also `Derived`. It is an instance of one or the other (even if instances of `Derived` also implement `base`).

Comment: Great answer to the post! helped me to understand in one go.

Comment: @JonathanWood - Instances of subtypes *are* instances of supertypes, that's fundamental to inheritance.